# Is using CompletableFuture safe? Will the correct execution of the async task be guaranteed?

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb

I wanted to use Asynchronous mode CompletableFuture Java 8 for servlet.

But found information:

> Thread creation is only prohibited in the EJB spec. To make the container more robust, it should be prohibited in the whole server process. Moving the thread creation from the EJBs to e.g. Servlets is not a reasonable solution.
>
> ...
>
> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage thread groups."

**Is using CompletableFuture safe? Will the correct execution of the async task be guaranteed?**

Comment: FWIW: I think this question may _really_ be asking, "Is using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` safe?" since that's what `CompletableFuture` uses in all of the methods where the caller does not explicitly provide a thread pool.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, it depends on how do you plan to use it.

In EE environment the only legal thread pool / executor service is managed executor:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html

Managed, because it's a resource managed and provided by server and could be injected in your EJBs.

```
@Resource(name = "wm/executorService")
ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
```

Having injected such resource, you are eligible to run async methods of CompletableFuture providing this managed executor explicitly:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                        yourBean::yourMethod,
                        managedExecutorService);
```